# average of one column in multi index dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I have a multi index dataframe similar to this.

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar','baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']),
      np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three','one', 'two','three'])]
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(9), index=arrays)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 2), index=arrays,columns=['C1','C2'])
df
```

I want to add a new column to the end of the dataframe that will group by level=0 ('bar','baz','foo') and average the numbers in column C2 for those groups.  I would like to show the same average number for each of the 3 separate rows at level=0 in one scenario (or alternatively at the top row for each level = 0) position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transform` `mean`

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform('mean')
                 C1        C2
bar one    0.473968 -0.454709
    two    0.473968 -0.454709
    three  0.473968 -0.454709
baz one    0.731266 -0.437691
    two    0.731266 -0.437691
    three  0.731266 -0.437691
foo one    0.061087 -0.326533
    two    0.061087 -0.326533
    three  0.061087 -0.326533
```

Update

```
df['C3']=df.groupby(level=0).C2.transform('mean')
```

Comment: This does the mean of all columns (C1 and C2).  I want to ADD a 3rd column (new_column) with the average of C2 based on level=0.  So I want to keep all the numbers the same in the existing dataframe but add a third coulmn with the results